# How to put an animation sprite on the desktop?

Tags: software-recommendation, compiz, animations

I want a small running bicycle (maybe an animation GIF) on the desktop, to remind me focus on work and work hard, can I?

It can be embedded in a small window, but it's better to remove the surrounding window border.

It's even better if it supports GIF-89a animation, so I can customize it whatever I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First install [shantz-xwinwrap from here](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/resources/downloads/shantz-xwinwrap.zip), then install gifsicle from the software center.
- Now create an empty file on the desktop, open it with gedit and then copy and paste [the content of this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/634070/) in it.
- Now save the file as gifbg , make it executable then run `gksu nautilus` and navigate to `/usr/bin/` and paste the file there .
- Now to use a .gif as a desktop background run `gifbg path/to/gif`
- If you want it to be your wallpaper at every boot then add `gifbg path/to/gif`  command to your startup applications .

***Source and detailed answers at:***

- [Linux Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=20508&start=0)
- [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=926519)

Comment: In the gifbg script, `-w WID` seems not work. And, I didn't see any difference running gifview alone, or running with xwinwrap. At last, running `gifview -a bike.gif` is just fine.

Comment: The pastebin link the second item no longer works; Could you somehow replace it? If the licence allows, just paste it as a code block; There is a  scrollbar added automatically if it is very long, no worries about that. Thanks